# Merge two ActiveRecord arrays and order by created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting, activerecord, merge

```
books = Book.find(:all)
articles = Articles.find(:all)
```

By reading from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html
I knew that I could do something like:

```
<%= render :partial => [customer1, employee1, customer2, employee2] %>
```

and it would use _customer and _employee partials as appropriate.

So I want to do something like that:

```
materials = books + articles
materials.sort_by_created_at
```

and in the view:

```
<%= render :partial => materials %>
```

How to do the merging and sorting of two ActiveRecord arrays???Thanks for help!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You're very close. Concatenating the arrays is done with the plus sign:

`materials = books + articles`

Sorting the combined array can be done by calling the `sort_by` method (mixed in from `Enumerable`) and passing in the attribute prefixed with `&:`

`materials.sort_by(&:created_at)`

This won't be good performance-wise for large result sets. You might consider deriving the Book and Article models from a parent class (like Material) if they are similar, using STI (Single Table Inheritance) to store them in the same table, and using `find` with an `order` clause, so the database can do the sorting for you.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `Array#concat` to merge two arrays.