# multiple has_many through relationships not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I was creating an attendance module for the participants. When teams select their events the values are getting stored in the selections table.

team.rb:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_details
  has_many :participants, through: :team_details

  has_many :selections
  has_many :events,through: :selections
end
```

team_detail.rb:

```
class TeamDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :participant
end
```

event.rb:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :selections
  has_many :teams,through: :selections
end
```

selection.rb:

```
class Selection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :event
end
```

but when I added attendance model through has_many through relationship so that I could mark attendance of each team according to the events in which it is participating the values were getting stored in attendances table instead of both selections and attendances table.

Here is the code after adding attendance model:

Event.rb:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :selections
  has_many :teams,through: :selections

  has_many :attendances
  has_many :teams, through: :attendances
end
```

attendance.rb:

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :event
end
```

team.rb:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_details
  has_many :participants, through: :team_details

  has_many :selections
  has_many :events,through: :selections

  has_many :attendances
  has_many :events, through: :attendances
end
```

what is the problem ? Can you suggest me a solution to this problem ?

I want attendance table as an independent active_record.

Comment: Adding two `has_many through:` relations to the same joined model is ambiguous. Consider if `selections` and `attendance` have different data - than what should `team.events` query? If the data is identical than you would not need two join tables.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is as follows:

```
has_many :selections
has_many :events, through: :selections

has_many :attendances
has_many :events, through: :attendances
```

A `has_many` association creates an instance method, which is populated with the collection data `ActiveRecord` pulls from the db. You can only have *one* instance method for each `class`... so the association is going to have either the events for `selections` or `attendances` data inside.

---

If you have two join tables with exactly the same data, you could rename the associations so they don't invoke the same instance method:

```
has_many :selections
has_many :selection_events, through: :selections, class_name: "Event", foreign_key: :event_id

has_many :attendances
has_many :attendance_events, through: :attendances, class_name: "Event", foreign_key: :event_id
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to just have `events`, you'd be best creating your own instance method, combining the two sets of data:

```
#app/models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :selections
    has_many :selection_events, through: :selections, class_name: "Event", foreign_key: :event_id

    has_many :attendances
    has_many :attendance_events, through: :attendances, class_name: "Event", foreign_key: :event_id

    def events
       attendance_events + selection_events
    end
end
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3593728/1143732)

--

Ultimately, if you're referencing the same data with two different join tables, it suggests you have major issues with the structure of your app.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir.  I sincerly appreciate it and would try to implement it. I have one more doubt If I just use only one join table *attendances* instead of *selections* will it be fine ?

Comment: It depends on the context; I didn't read most of the question. I only saw the error I highlighted, and wrote the fix

Comment: I want to store the team ids and and the event ids in which each team is participating. Using selection table i was just team ids and event ids. Where each team can have multiple event ids. If i use attendances instead of using selections and attendances both. Will it affect it ?

Comment: So your users are part of a team through selection; teams are parts of events?

Comment: Users are part of team through *team details* and teams and events are part of selections.

Comment: Okay, what is the purpose of selections?

Comment: Just to store team ids and their event ids. But attendance model is performing the same function but with other attributes also like *round status* and *status* -to store present or absent status.

Comment: I think i should remove selections table and use attendance table as it is storing same values as selections table.

Comment: I couldn't agree more :)

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem, but it's not fixed yet. I want to get it fixed

Comment: I will fix it and tell you asap. :)